# How do artists develop their style on drawing line art?

Tags: drawing

I want to know about how artists develop their style on line art, everyone has a different line art style based on their preferences and they draw irregular lines with irregular width and length in the shapes they draw, what ways do they develop their line art style?

Comment: Mostly it comes from doing: lots of experimentation and practice. Beyond that there is no one answer.